# Expressionengine Let user know if url_title is already used

Tags: expressionengine

I have a safecracker form that allows users to enter title, url_title body content. If url_title is already in used, by default, a numerical number gets added to url_title so it’s unique. But instead of having this automated behavior where number gets added to url_title, Is there a way i can notify the user that the url_title typed is already taken so user can enter a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the `{url_title}` in your SafeCracker form *on the fly before submission*, you could write an Ajax routine that would check and compare the value of the `<input />` against the `url_title` column in the `exp_channel_titles` database table.

When SafeCracker was being developed by [Barrett Newton](http://barrettnewton.com/), there used to be [Developer documentation](http://barrettnewton.com/safecracker/user_guide/development/) for Custom Fieldtypes and Extension Hooks, but since EllisLab took over SafeCracker I believe they've been removed.

However, since SafeCracker handles its server-side form validation using the [CodeIgniter Form Validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html), you should be able to extend the validation class to meet your needs by creating a [callback function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) to validate the `{url_title}` on form submission, instead of silently allowing ExpressionEngine to append a digit to the field data.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into the validation class